# Como saber se houve falha ao enviar SMS?

Tags: java, android, sms

Tenho esse método de envio de SMS via aplicação:

```
public boolean enviaSMS(String fone, String mensagem) throws Exception {
    try {
        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(fone, null,
                smsManager.divideMessage(mensagem), null, null);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Porém, o Android nunca retorna `exception` caso não consiga enviar, existe algum meio de obter o `exception` quando houve alguma falha no envio?

Comment: Verifique o log no Logcat que deve aparecer uma mensagem de erro

Comment: Já tinha verificado, o método só retorna exception caso o numero de telefone esteja nulo ou vazio, e a mensagem a mesma coisa, mas não retorna o status do envio, se foi enviado, se deu erro, etc... há algo que possa ser feito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Falhas de envio não lançam excepção, elas são reportadas de outra forma.

Se olhar para a assinatura do método [sendMultipartTextMessage](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultipartTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E%29) verá que ele recebe dois `Arrays<PendingIntent>`, *sentIntents* e *deliveryIntents*.

```
public void sendMultipartTextMessage (String destinationAddress,
                                      String scAddress,
                                      ArrayList<String> parts,
                                      ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents,
                                      ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents)
```

Eles(PendingIntent) são utilizados para notificar o estado de envio e entrega de cada parte da *MultipartTextMessage*.

Comece por criar dois *BroadcastReceiver*, um para receber a notificação do estado de envio e outro para receber a notificação do estado de entrega.

**SentReceiver.java**

```
public class SentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static SentReceiver instance;

    private SentReceiver(){

    }

    public static SentReceiver getInstance(){

        if(instance == null)instance = new SentReceiver();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        switch (getResultCode()){
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "SMS(parte) enviado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                toast = Toast.makeText(context, "No service",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

**DeliveredReceiver.java**

```
public class DeliveredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static DeliveredReceiver instance;

    private DeliveredReceiver(){

    }

    public static DeliveredReceiver getInstance(){

        if(instance == null)instance = new DeliveredReceiver();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "SMS(parte) entregue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                toast = Toast.makeText(context, "SMS(parte) não entregue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

No método `enviaSMS()` crie os `Array<PendingIntent>` e passe-os ao método `sendMultipartTextMessage()`.

```
public void enviaSMS(Context context, String fone, String mensagem) {

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<String> messages = smsManager.divideMessage(mensagem);
    int messagesCount = messages.size();

    //Criar os PendingIntent
    PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                               new Intent("aSuaPackage.SMS_SENT"),
                               PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                                    new Intent("aSuaPackage.SMS_DELIVERED"),
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Preenche os arrays
    for(int i=0; i<messagesCount; i++){
        sentIntents.add(piSent);
        deliveryIntents.add(piDelivered);
    }

    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(fone, null, messages, 
                                        sentIntents, deliveryIntents);             
}
```

Para registar os *receivers* use:

```
registerReceiver(SentReceiver.getInstance(), new IntentFilter("aSuaPackage.SMS_SENT"));
registerReceiver(DeliveredReceiver.getInstance(), new IntentFilter("aSuaPackage.SMS_DELIVERED"));
```

Comment: Só para incrementar a resposta,  nunca caia no catch pois "try catch" são adicionados para tratar exceções em tempo de execução. Nesse caso não caia no catch porque não tinha erro de execução. E como o ramaral explicou faltou adicionar os pendingIntent para ser notificado dos listener de estado de entrega do sms.

Comment: @AlessandroBarreto Obrigado pela nota.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso, resolveu o meu problema.