# Verificar o estado dos cartões SIM 1 e SIM 2 num dispositivo Dual SIM

Tags: android

A resposta a cima respondeu a parte do meu problema, so que agora surgiu outra questão.

Como fazer para verificar o estado dos cartões SIM 1 e SIM 2 num dispositivo Dual SIM?

Neste momento tenho a solução implementada da seguinte forma:

```
if (phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cartão SIM não Disponível - Não e Possível Enviar SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (!enabled) {
                // check if enabled and if not send user to the GPS settings
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ative a Localização Por Favor...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                if (telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                        //Do not need to check the permission
                        //getLocation();
                        sendSMS();
                    } else {
                        if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
                            //If you have already permitted the permission
                            //getLocation();
                            sendSMS();
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cartão SIM não Disponível - Não e Possível Enviar SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
```

Com esta implementação falha em alguns dispositivos Dual SIM, como poderei verificar e fazer condições para os casos de o SIM1 ter cartão activo, ou vice-versa?

Comment: O que é que "falha em alguns dispositivos Dual SIM"?

Comment: Enviei a app a um colega com um dispositivo Dual SIM, mas no qual apenas está a usar um cartão SIM e ele refere que ao clickar no button referente a função que envia um SMS a app crasha totalmente. Como não tenho o dispositivo comigo, não consigo fazer debug, mas a unica coisa que penso que possa ser é alguma questão relacionada com o ser dual SIM. Uma vez que eu faç a verificação do SIM_STATE_READY.

Comment: Eu tenho uma aplicação que envia SMS e não necessitei de fazer qualquer tipo de verificação(tipo de dispositivo ou se tem SIM) apenas verifico se o SMS foi enviado e se não a sua causa.Veja nesta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112548/2541) como isso é feito.

Comment: Eu fiz essa verificação uma vez que a minha app poderá ser usada em Smartphones ou Tablet's e nos casos dos tablet's sem SIM, ao chamar essa funcionalidade iria falhar... Esse é o motivo de fazer a verificação...

Comment: A aplicação que referi não falha no caso de tablet's, se o envio falhar por essa razão informa "Serviço não disponível". Você pode saber se é dual SIM usando `telephonyManager..getPhoneCount()` no entanto requer minSDK 23. O método `telephonyManager.getSimState()` deveria funcionar mesmo em dispositivos Dual SIM.

Comment: Eu também tenho um dispositivo Dual SIM e não consigo reproduzir o erro relatado por ele!

Comment: Sendo assim só fazendo debug com esse dispositivo poderá descobrir a razão do problema.